# SQL - AVG() on * fields

Tags: sql, average, openoffice-base

I want to average all values on a table with many fields.

My data looks like this

```
col1  col2  col3  ...  col100
----  ----  ----       ------
1     1     1          1
2     4     8          16
3     9     27         81
```

And to output all the AVG() values in a query, like so:

```
col1  col2  col3  ... col100
----  ----  ----       ------
2     4.67  12        32.67
```

The following query gives an error.

```
SELECT AVG(*) FROM table
```

Is there any SQL code to AVG() all fields without explicitly naming them?

Note: Using OpenOffice Base.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367750/average-of-multiple-columns

Comment: Not that I am aware of (cool if there is). If this is one time use and those numbers are sequential, you can use a spreadsheet to help with writing out the 100 column names in a select statement.  @A.O - did you miss his question?, the link you posted doesn't help answer "Is there any SQL code to AVG() all fields without explicitly naming them?".

Comment: This is part of a much bigger dataset. The averages (and sigmas, etc.) then have to be related to other tables in order to get analysis done. Normally, I use spreadsheets, but with the amount of data being collected, it'd be more useful to scale up to databases... if it's possible...

Comment: As per Chris Albert's answer, I doubt you'll find a solution to this problem.  The biggest issue you have is the table design.  Col1 - col100 is something reminscent of flat files and early databases.  There are quite a few data structures that would be much more suited for what you are asking for here...it's not that what you're asking for can't be done, it just can't be done in this format.

Comment: If you use denormalized data, you have to write denormalized and deoptimized queries to get the answer you want.  Normalize the data and the query becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that without explicitly naming every column. This is the documentation from technet.

[Technet AVG](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx)