# How to deal with null values while DIVIDING

Tags: sql, select, null, sql-server-2014, ssms-2014

I have a simple looking problem but I don't know how to handle.
I have tow columns which are filled by value or `null`.

I have to make an average of these like this:

1. if in both are values = (A+B)/2
2. if one is null then = A or B.

Is it possible to write it in different way then:

```
 case when a is not null and b is not null then....
 etc.
```

If I use a simple `(a+b)/2` I get `null` in cases where one of values is `null`.

Comment: `coalesce((a+b)/2,b,a)`?

Comment: What should be the value if both A,B are NULL?

Comment: um... maybe I'm missing something but AVG() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367750/average-of-multiple-columns and check martin's answer.

Comment: @TZHX, please add it as a solution and I'll remove mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to use `outer apply` with `avg()` because `avg()` ignores `NULL` values:

```
select v.avg_ab
from t outer apply
     (select avg(x) as avg_ab
      from (values (t.A), (t.B)
           ) v
     ) v;
```

You can also do this with a complicated `case` expression:

```
select (case when A is not NULL and B is not NULL then (A + B) / 2
             when A is not NULL then A
             when B is not NULL then B
        end) as avg_ab
. . .
```

This works well enough for 2 values; it is feasible for 3.  It doesn't generalize well beyond that.  Another way to use `case` is a bit more generalizable:

```
select ( (coalesce(A, 0) + coalesce(B, 0)) /
         ((case when A is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when B is not null then 1 else 0 end)
         )
       )
```

But the `apply` method is still simpler.

Comment: This is a terrible solution for the OP request.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the case when they are both `null` should result in a `null` average, you can use the mathematical "trick" of `(A+A)/2=A` and use `coalesce` to write this in a pretty elegant fashion, IMHO:

```
(COALESCE(a, b) + COALESCE(b, a)) / 2
```

Comment: I always forget about COALESCE!

Comment: Well and if I have four of them? Then I would have to use: (a,b,c,d) and all transformations? And if one of them is not not null then I would divide by 2 only one value, right?

Answer (score 1):

This would be the cleanest solution

```
select  coalesce((A+B)/2,A,B)
```

.
.
.

Demo:

```
declare @t table (id int,A int,B int)

insert into @t values (1,30,50),(2,30,null),(3,null,50),(4,null,null)

select  id,A,B,coalesce((A+B)/2,A,B) as result   
from    @t
```

---

```
+----+------+------+--------+
| id | A    | B    | result |
+----+------+------+--------+
| 1  | 30   | 50   | 40     |
+----+------+------+--------+
| 2  | 30   | NULL | 30     |
+----+------+------+--------+
| 3  | NULL | 50   | 50     |
+----+------+------+--------+
| 4  | NULL | NULL | NULL   |
+----+------+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT (ISNULL(a, b)+ISNULL(b, a))/2
```