# In Rails how to get the average of the substract of two datetime columns

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to get the average of `updated_at - created_at` datetime columns

I tried this way but it does not work as I expected:

```
User.average('updated_at - created_at')
```

It is giving this sql query:

```
SELECT AVG(updated_at-created_at) FROM `users`
```

When I filter by one ID getting one object it is revealing me different result than `user.updated_at - user.created_at`. That is why I think my sql query is not correct.

```
User.where(id: 3).average('updated_at - created_at').to_f => 29183.0

user = User.find(3) # (created_at: "2018-07-25 09:58:56", updated_at: "2018-07-25 12:50:39")
user.updated_at - user.created_at => 10303.0
```

Comment: see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/7368597/4758119

Comment: Providing sample data where you think you are getting wrong output will help.

Comment: @skelwa I added an example of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @DeepakMahakale not sure if it that case helps. I want to do the substract of two columns and then calculate the average of the results.

Comment: Can you try using DATEDIFF(updated_at, created_at) inside average?

Comment: Yes @skelwa, it returns 0.0

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found my own answer using [`TIME_TO_SEC`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) and [`TIMEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) inside AVG:

```
User.where(id: 3)
    .average('TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(updated_at, created_at))')
    .to_f
 => 10303.0
```