# Dynamic horizontal aggregate (AVG)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, average

I have a table which contains 3 float(nullable) columns:

```
Value1  ||  Value2  ||  Value3 
NULL        NULL        100.00
10.00       20.00       NULL
10.00       10.00       100.00
```

I need to get the average from these field (value1+value2+value3 / 3), but the divider is actually how many of these field that has value. So the expected result would be :

```
Value1  ||  Value2  ||  Value3 || AVG
NULL        NULL        100.00    100.00 (from 100/1)
10.00       20.00       NULL      15.00  (from 30/2)
10.00       10.00       100.00    40.00  (from 120/3)
```

Anyone can help?

I've tried a solution according to this thread :
[Average of multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367750/average-of-multiple-columns)

But didn't seem to work.

I've also tried to handle this in C#, in which i use `for` loop and a counter to determine the divider, and then divide them. It actually works, but i prefer to handle this via query, because it took too much time when the records went over 3000 row(s).

My current query:

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT AVG(c)
        FROM   (VALUES(Value1),
                      (Value2),
                      (Value3)) T (c)) AS [Average]
FROM   tbl_trans_score
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: @mkRabbani sorry, i edited my post

Comment: Check out my answer.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this below script-

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN (COALESCE(Value1,0)+COALESCE(Value2,0)+COALESCE(Value3,0)) = 0 THEN 0 
    ELSE
    (
        COALESCE(Value1,0)+
        COALESCE(Value2,0)+
        COALESCE(Value3,0)
    )/
    (
        CASE WHEN Value1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END+ 
        CASE WHEN Value2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END+ 
        CASE WHEN Value3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
    )
END
FROM your_table
```

Comment: We can add an operator in `CASE WHEN`? I'm sorry i didn't know this before, gonna try this for sure.

Comment: Sorry for late response. This works best for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One method using a sub query and the `VALUES` operator to normalise the data:

```
SELECT V.Value1,
       V.Value2,
       V.Value3,
       A.Average
FROM (VALUES(NULL ,NULL ,100.00),
            (10.00,20.00,NULL),
            (10.00,10.00,100.00))V(Value1,Value2,Value3)
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT AVG(L.[Value]) AS Average
                  FROM (VALUES(V.Value1),
                              (V.Value2),
                              (V.Value3)) L([Value])) A;
```

Comment: This is the best approach in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 way to solved your problem...

**First Way:**

```
SELECT AVG (Vals) AVG_COL
FROM 
(
SELECT Row_Num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
) ,
Value1,Value2,Value3
FROM tblFloat ) UNPIVOT_SOURCE
UNPIVOT
( 
Vals FOR Cols IN ( Value1,Value2,Value3 )
) UNPIVOT_HANDLER
GROUP BY
Row_Num
```

[image: Output -->1]

**Second Way:**

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(
        CONVERT(
            DECIMAL(10, 2),
            1.0 *
            (
                ISNULL(Value1, 0 ) + ISNULL( Value2, 0 ) + ISNULL( Value3, 0 ) 
            )
            /
            NULLIF(
                ISNULL(SIGN(ABS(Value1)),0) + ISNULL(SIGN(ABS(Value2)),0) + ISNULL(SIGN(ABS(Value3)),0)
            ,0 )
        ) ,
        COALESCE(Value1,Value2,Value3)
    )
FROM tblFloat
```

[image]