# How to get the average of multiple columns with NULL in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

`AVG` function in PostgreSQL ignores NULL values when it calculates the average. But what if I want to count the average value of multiple columns with many NULL values?

All of below commands dont work

```
AVG(col1,col2,col3)
AVG(col1)+AVG(col2)+AVG(col3) -> sum calculation alone gives wrong value because of null calculation
```

This question is similar to this [Average of multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367750/average-of-multiple-columns), but is there any simple solution for PostgreSQL specific case?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7368597/330315) of the linked question will work in Postgres as well (if you remove the dreaded square brackets)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, you just pointed out my problem